# English translation of a Russian paper by Gordin and Lifšic

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, translation

Unfortunately I can't read Russian, I was wondering if there is an English translation of this paper

“The central limit theorem for stationary Markov processes”, Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR, 239:4 (1978), 766–767

I apologize in advance if this is not the suitable place to make this question.

Comment: The paper, available in original form at http://www.mathnet.ru/links/c6486f384b0ab5aeb7e0dee994974fad/dan41622.pdf, is quite short. From this .pdf you can copy and paste the text into Google Translate yourself, perhaps a bit at a time, and what comes out (ignoring the notation, which is math rather than Russian) seems reasonable for computer translation. Its first suggested translation for Доказательство is "Evidence" rather than the more standard "Proof", but in context I think you could figure out what was meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This journal was transllated into English as
[Soviet Mathematics. Doklady](https://www.worldcat.org/title/soviet-mathematics-doklady/oclc/312040373) Many US libraries subscribed it.
If you have access to a university library, and it does not have it, use ILL.

Here is the exact reference for the translation:

Gordin, M. I.; Lifshits, B. A.
The central limit theorem for stationary Markov processes. (English. Russian original) Zbl 0395.60057

Sov. Math., Dokl. 19, 392-394 (1978); translation from Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 239, 766-767 (1978).